# pubspec.yaml enviroment: sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0 '

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have been designated as such. However, if I set my enviroment to ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
! and other errors occur.

my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

vscode output

> [ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/third_party/protobuf/examples] dart pub get
> pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint. You should edit
> pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:
>
> environment:   sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'
>
> See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-constraint exit code 65

flutter doctor -v output

> • Flutter version 2.5.1 at /Users/t/Developer/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision ffb2ecea52 (8 days ago), 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
> • Engine revision b3af521a05
> • Dart version 2.14.2